# purchase_url is not available by getting soundcloud stream collection via SC.get()

Tags: javascript, soundcloud

I'm requesting 50 tracks from main soundcloud stream with
    `SC.get('/me/activities/tracks/affiliated', params, function(stream, error)`

I get most of the data except purchase_url. However i noticed that this property is available if i query for playlists
`SC.get('/playlists/' + playlist.origin.id + '/tracks', function(data)`

I know i could get all track data by having 50 get requests for each track but that does not sound reasonable. As the returned stream collection contains about 99% of track properties, i do not understand why purchase_url is missing.

So, my question is, is there a way to get the user's main feed with ALL track properties? What are your experiences? I really do not want to have 50 separate calls just for this 1 property

**EDIT:** just for clarification, by main feed i mean the affiliated url, the list of posts that are from users you follow, NOT your own uploaded sounds/playlists etc

Comment: sorry, for correction the purchase_url property is present but its value is always null when getting "/me/activities/tracks/affiliated"

Comment: I noticed the same thing. If I query the individual tracks, though, I see purchase URL's and titles.

Answer (score 0):

You can - I'm doing that right here: https://github.com/jkoudys/janeswalk-web/blob/ca345fa801517adad220558fd1e9ecd1781c27d9/themes/janeswalk/js/components/caw/map/SoundCloudConnect.jsx#L27

I'm not using the SC lib, rather just querying the service endpoints directly through `jQuery.ajax()`. Doc for that endpoint is here: https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/reference#playlists

In my example, I grab all tracks for all of the current user's playlists.

Comment: I don't have a problem with playlists :) Perhaps my description is misleading? If i query for playlists (/playlists/{playlistID}) i do get the purchase_url for each track. The problem is the main feed / affiliated stream (the users you follow) where each track will have a null value for purchase_url

Comment: The purchase_url ought to be included in that, at least according to their spec. Try it using the http endpoint directly -- if it doesn't show up there, that sounds like a bug to report to soundcloud.

Comment: tried it, same results. i have contacted them trough their support form. i will post the answer if there will be any. thanks for your answers :)

Comment: no response from soundcloud as of today. is there any better option for bug reporting than their support form?